# How do I load specific rows from a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a .txt file with many rows and columns of data and a list containing integer values. How would I load the row numbers in the text file which match the integers in the list?

To illustrate, say I have a list of integers:

```
a = [1,3,5]
```

How would I read only rows 1,3 and 5 from a text file into an array?

The loadtxt routine in numpy let's you both skip rows and use particular columns. But I can't seem to find a way to do something along the lines of (ignoring incorrect syntax):

```
new_array = np.loadtxt('data.txt', userows=a, unpack='true')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the text file too big/take too long to load into memory?

Comment: Using `numpy` to achieve this is a requirement?

Comment: Can't you use a standard `while open(file) as fd: for n, line in enumerate(fd)` loop and if `n` equals anything in `a` do your stuff?

Comment: The text file is not that big, but the array 'a' will change during the program so the rows to be read will change all the time. Numpy is not a strict requirement.

Comment: Is your list actually stored like that in the text file? Or is it in a format where it could be read by a CSV reader or Pandas?

Comment: A CSV reader could read it. The data contains only rows and columns of numbers.

Comment: Pardon my stupidity Fredrik, but assuming the grey area is all code, writing 'as' will not work (syntax issue) also what is 'fd' in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul, see the docs for [the with statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). In Fredrik's comment, `fd` is an alias for the file object opened with `open(file, 'r')`.

Comment: Yes, @Bill, @Fredrik meant to write `with` not `while`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given this file:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18
19,20,21
```

You can use the csv module to get the desired np array:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

desired=[1,3,5]
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    result=[[int(s) for s in row] for i,row in enumerate(reader) if i in desired]

print(np.array(result))
```

Prints:

```
[[ 4  5  6]
 [10 11 12]
 [16 17 18]]
```

Comment: He asked for a .txt file, not .csv

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on my comment

```
$ cat file.txt
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = [1, 4, 8]

with open('file.txt') as fd:
    for n, line in enumerate(fd):
        if n in a:
            print line.strip()
```

output:

```
$ ./l.py 
line 1
line 4
line 8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can stick to using numpy's `loadtxt` method, except that you'll need to pass a generator object to the function instead of the file path.

First define a generator that accepts filename and row indices and yields only those lines at the specified indices

```
def generate_specific_rows(filePath, userows=[]):
    with open(filePath) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i in userows:
                yield line
```

Now you can pass create a generator object and pass it to the `loadtxt` method

```
a = [1,3,5]
gen = generate_specific_rows('data.txt', userows=a)
new_array = np.loadtxt(gen, unpack='true')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CSV module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [`Files.xreadlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=xreadlines#file.xreadlines).

> - `CSV module`: implements classes to read and write tabular data in    CSV format
> - `Files.xreadlines()`: Return an iterator over the keys of the dictionary. This is a shortcut for iterkeys().
>     Deprecated since version 2.3: Use `for line in file` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `line.split ()` instead of `line.strip()`. 
`line.split ()` returns the list, which can be easily converted to `numpy.array` by using `np.asarray` command.