# effectively preprocessing record array from genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I imported a csv file into a record array using `genfromtxt`.

Its first and second column are longitude and latitude, so integer, and the other four columns are names and ids, so they may be defined as string.

So what I want is,

1. storing the first and second column as a separate 2D array of integers so that it is easier to do calculations
2. considering subsets of rows, not entire rows, by filtering rows by an id in the fourth column. At this time I am considering only one group(id == 19), but I will want to do this for all the other ids.

What follows is my attempt so far.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np

data = genfromtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=",", dtype=None) 
ket_idx = ()
latlon = []

for rows in xrange(len(data)):
    if data[rows][4] == 19:
        ket_idx += (rows, )

for k_i in ket_idx:
    print data[k_i][4]
```

I have no idea what to do for 1, and I think my way of doing 2 is very inefficient.
This is almost the first time I am coding in Python, and I couldn't find right answers online.
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991814/how-do-i-load-specific-rows-from-a-txt-file-in-python

Comment: @AbidRahmanK The reason I do not do it that way is because I have hundreds of ids and most of them will be considered later, although I am only considering one id.

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `data`.  I suspect it is a 1D array with a multifield dtype.  You access the 'columns' by field name.  Search for `recarray` tutorial or reference pages (or SO questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular 2D numpy array,

1. use `data[:,:2]` to get the first and second column.
2. use [boolean index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays): `data[data[:,4]==19]`

demo:

```
In [405]: a #"a" is a 2D ndarray
Out[405]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 2]])

In [406]: a[:,1]==2
Out[406]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [407]: a[a[:,1]==2]
Out[407]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 2]])
```

**UPDATE:**
For a structured array, see [how to manipulate it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays):

1) use `data.dtype.names` or address columns by name:

e.g.,

```
In [556]: d
Out[556]: 
array([(1, 2, 'foo', 'bar', 19), (11, 22, 'foo', 'bar', 18),
       (3, 4, 'foo', 'xxx', 19)], 
      dtype=[('lat', '<i4'), ('long', '<i4'), ('name1', 'S10'), ('name2', 'S10'), ('id', '<i4')])

In [557]: d[['lat', 'long']] #get the first column if you know their names
Out[557]: 
array([(1, 2), (11, 22), (3, 4)], 
      dtype=[('lat', '<i4'), ('long', '<i4')])

In [558]: d[list(d.dtype.names[:2])] #get the first column by index
Out[558]: 
array([(1, 2), (11, 22), (3, 4)], 
      dtype=[('lat', '<i4'), ('long', '<i4')])
```

2) similar to mask indexing a regular array:

e.g.,

```
In [562]: d[d['id']==19]
Out[562]: 
array([(1, 2, 'foo', 'bar', 19), (3, 4, 'foo', 'xxx', 19)], 
      dtype=[('lat', '<i4'), ('long', '<i4'), ('name1', 'S10'), ('name2', 'S10'), ('id', '<i4')])
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you add some more explanation for your demo section?

Comment: Also, indexing with `data` does not work like numpy array, because it's a structured array. for example, `data[:,1]` throws an error. That's why I posted this question.